# java ASCII invertido

Tags: java, ascii

```
         char palabra[] = new char[91];
  char Descenso = 0;
  for (int i = palabra.length-1; i>=0; --i)
  {
   
      palabra[i]=Descenso;
      Descenso--;
  }
  for(int i = palabra.length-1; i>=65; --i)
  {
      System.out.println("El numero es: "+i+" La letra es: "+palabra[i]);
```

¿Como hacer para invertir las letras?
a la hora de hacerlo no me salen las letras, y me salen otros símbolos.

Comment: Al arreglo palabras le asignas valores de cero hacia abajo. Eso no es correcto.

Comment: Ok voy revisarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo quieres lograr es lo siguiente:

```
// iterar desde la Z hasta la A
for (int i = 'Z'; i >= 'A'; --i) {
    // se usa (char) i para convertir el número en caracter
    System.out.println("El numero es: " + i + " La letra es: " + (char) i);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.